# How to access getlist items in django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

This is my template :

```
{% for pr in productlist %}

<ul name="myList">
  <li>{{ pr.productname }} <input type="hidden" name="mylist" id="prname" value="{{ pr.productname }}"></li>
  <li><input type="number" name="mylist" id="prnumber"/></li>
</ul>

{endfor}
```

in this list i have items or more. i using getlist() method and can print items in view. here is my view :

```
data = request.POST.getlist("mylist")
for item in (data)):
     print (item)
```

result is :

```
 product1
 1

 product2
 6

 product3
 4
```

but when try to print item.prnumber it raise error. like:

```
 data = request.POST.getlist("mylist")
 for item in (data)):
     print (item.prnumber)
```

**how i can print just numbers?**

Comment: Can you  add the code of your `views.py`

Comment: i added already @Poornaka

Comment: No, I mean the complete view

Comment: @Poornaka view is simple just this i write matter part.

Comment: So you want to access the getlist items in the template pls explain...

Comment: @Poornaka i edited my question,please review again. i want just get index of items and save in db one by one using for loop

Comment: havent you used a model for this case?

Comment: @Poornaka question is simple, how can i get item.prnumber? in fact how can i get list items one by one?

Comment: What is the error that it raised? example - TypeError